# Multiple Arrays in DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

So I am working on a project and am having trouble trying to use multiple arrays of data in a data table.

The issue I am running into is my initial set of data comes from a sharepoint list call(the calculations variable).

I then use values in that array to run some calculations and put those into their own array(formulatedNumbers).

I have my DataTable filling the first 6 columns with data fine(with the calculations array), the issue is getting the second array(formulatedNumbers) into the 7th column.

My javascript buiding the datatable is below

TL;DR After I use the first array to fill in columns 1-6, I want to use another array to fill in column 7.

```
function displayCalculations() {
    $("#table_id").dataTable().fnDestroy();
    var calculations = getRateData();
    var formulatedNumbers = [];

    for(i=0; i<calculations.length; i++) {
        formulatedNumbers.push(calculations[i].annum * calculations[i].dailyDecimal * 1000);
    }

    console.log(formulatedNumbers);

    $('#table_id').DataTable(
        {
            data: calculations,
            "columns": 
            [
                { "data": "startDate" },
                { "data": "endDate" },
                { "data": "dayTotal" },
                { "data": "annum" },
                { "data": "dailyRate" },
                { "data": "dailyDecimal" }
            ],
        }); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest just adding the new attribute to each item in `calculations`.

```js
function displayCalculations() {
    $("#table_id").dataTable().fnDestroy();
    var calculations = getRateData();

    calculations.forEach(item =>
        item.newField = item.annum * item.dailyDecimal * 1000);

    console.log(calculations);

    $('#table_id').DataTable(
        {
            data: calculations,
            "columns": 
            [
                { "data": "startDate" },
                { "data": "endDate" },
                { "data": "dayTotal" },
                { "data": "annum" },
                { "data": "dailyRate" },
                { "data": "dailyDecimal" },
                { "data": "newField" } // + ADDED
            ],
        }); 
}
```

Comment: Ah okay I will give this a go and report back!

Comment: So after the forEach the console.log returns undefined. I added a console log before it and it pulls the initial data in, but after the forEach is undefined.

Comment: So I removed the calculations = part of your example and it worked! So answer will be accepted!

Comment: No problem at all!

Answer (score 2):

Don’t create new array for the calculated values but add them to your other data

```
calculations = calculations.map(calculation =>
{
    return calculation.push(calculation.annum * calculation.dailyDecimal * 1000);
}
```

Comment: I already accepted, but have an upvote! This would work as well. Adding to my data didn't occur to me only because well I haven't had uses for it enough. Appreciate the alternative answer!

Comment: This would just push the values to the array with no key though correct?

Comment: Yes, but datatables does not need a key. It uses index

Comment: Indeed. Just wanted to confirm that!